# Are there known situations where the non-deterministic property of QM is notisable in human perceptions (seconds to hours or cm to meters)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism

QM is non-deterministic. In QM you can calculater the **chance** that a particle is at a certain position. But as a human we cannot experiance one particl, only a vast number of particles (eg constant of Avogadro). And time in QM is order of magnitudes smaller than what humans can experiance.
So this is the question: are there processes where the outcome is for a human notisable non deterministic because of QM behaviour?

Comment: A geiger counter?

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I meant. In a QM lab you obviously have results that translate QM behavour into ie print or graphics. I mean systems outside the QM lab and in every day life. Something similar as the weather system where the famous butterfly will cause an huricane (question here would be what are the odds, one in a million years? so not within human experiance). It is a theoretical questions